# Symbolic link (ln) operation not supported Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, symlink

During a model training, I got this error:

[image: failed to create symbolic link: Operation not supported]

First I thought it was maybe a problem with my path, but it wasn't, and I discovered that a colab session does not support the symbolic link (ln) operation, for most of the ways you could run it (also with os.system):

[image: ln operation not supported]

My question is: Are there any other ways that I did not explore? or did someone get the same error with Colab? (not specifically with **ln**, but any other not supported operation)

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive does not support symbolic link as it is a feature of Linux storage system. However, using the files directly in Colab, given that they can fit in, you can most definitely keep symbolic links. I would recommend compressing them and storing them if it's necessary to keep them in the drive.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the wrong path.

Try changing from

```
/content/mydrive
```

To

```
/content/My Drive
```

Also check with

```
!ls "/content/My Drive/path/to/yourfile"
```

That the file really exists there.

Comment: for the ```/content/mydrive``` it is just the result of: ```ln -s "/content/drive/My Drive" "/content/mydrive" ```, because I thought the space maybe the problem, but it was not. and no, the file does not exist there.